# No module named googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk

I'm receiving this error when trying to install `Google Assistant`, and I am using `Windows 10`, `Python 3.6` and `SDK 0.3.3`. Could someone please recommend the next step? I've tried inputting in the string recommended on other sites, which ends with `--scope https://googleapis.com...` but this did not work.

Comment: I've googled it, and it didn't work. The proposed solution was to input "pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]".  Then, I followed the next step of inputting "google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets path/to/client_secret_XXXXX.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless" and I got the same result.

Comment: So far, I've reinstalled the latest Python, making sure the options in 'advanced' were selected and opting not to have the limited character string. Then, I tried this website https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation which provides a way to download the library. However, I first needed to go back into command prompt as an administrator for it to allow me to install it. Still working on this...

Answer (score 4):

Easy fix but hard to find. You just need to make sure that all the settings are there as mentioned before. I completed the above actions, and then I set it to administrator and input the 3 commands:
`pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

`pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]`

`google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets path/to/client_secret_XXXXX.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless`

Success!

Comment: This worked to get me through authentication with the password/key. However, after doing that, it went back to not recognizing the files- even after being installed.

Answer (score 1):

After running command: 
google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets c:\client_secret_XXXXX.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless

On very next line, it says: Please visit this URL to authorize this application

Open this link and authorize on google and it will provide authorization code, enter this code against "Enter the authorization code:" and you are done.