# "google-oauthlib-tool: command not found" when trying to install google assistant on raspbian

Tags: python, raspbian, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to install google assistant on a newly set up pi 3 with Raspbian. I got the message "No module named googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers" so I followed the instructions given in answer to this question: [No module named googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779671/no-module-named-googlesamples-assistant-auth-helpers)

The first 2 commands appear to complete OK, but the third command gives 
"google-oauthlib-tool: command not found"

My programming skills are too rusty to work out what's going wrong.

Python 3.5.3;  forgotten how to find the version of SDK, but should be the latest one.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: .. finishing the tour possible... or still to rusty ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Have you followed [the instructions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/install-sample#configure_the_environment) to set up a virtual Python environment?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-venv 
# Use python3.4-venv if the package cannot be found.
python3 -m venv env
env/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
source env/bin/activate
```

Then you should be able to install [the oauth tool](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/install-sample#generate_credentials) with pip:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]
```

You can display all of your installed packages using `pip freeze`

```
pip freeze | grep google
```

Comment: ```
env/bin/pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]
zsh: no matches found: google-auth-oauthlib[tool]
``` :( ???

Comment: Following guide [here.](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-nodejs/tree/668a4a1917b7793c3d07f69076d36591ac960646)

Comment: Resolved. Had to do this: `"google-auth-oauthlib[tool]"` - used `""` :| ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Before running `python -m pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]` , run

```
pip install google-auth
```

And then:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]
```

`google-auth` is a dependency of `google-auth-oauthlib` in Raspbian

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate the tool via `locate google-oauthlib-tool`

Then, cd into the path and open it there with your arguments