# PROBLEM WITH INSTALLING GOOGLE ASSISTANT "No module named googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers"

Tags: python, windows-10, google-assist-api

Hey I'm trying to get google assistant on my Windows 10 pc by following this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKUlgDdLVe0

as I am going through the steps I run into a problem when typing this command:

```
input:
        py -m googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers --client-secrets path/to/.json 

output:
        D:\Documents\python.exe: No module named googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers
```

things I've tried but didn't work:

- Made sure I did all the steps    correctly (went through multiple
  times)
- Reinstalling python with    checking all the right boxes
- running cmd as administrator and also    running it normally
- I checked all other threads

Commands Ive tried:

- `pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]`
- `google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets path/to/client_secret_XXXXX.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless`
- `python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk`
- `python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.audio_helpers`
- `google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk- prototype \ --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gcm \--save --headless --client-secrets D:\Documents\GoogleAssistant\<MyFile.json>`
- `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

Different threads about the subject:

- [When installing Google Assistant, I an error "...googlesamples.assistant' is a package and cannot be directly executed..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091251/when-installing-google-assistant-i-an-error-googlesamples-assistant-is-a-p)
- [No module named googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779671/no-module-named-googlesamples-assistant-auth-helpers)
- https://github.com/warchildmd/google-assistant-hotword-raspi/issues/17